Convert React Native Project to .AAR or any SDK libraries and add it to Android Project
I am planning to convert my existing React Native Project to .aar or any sdk that can be add to my existing android project. There are no proper documentation regarding this on the documentation, I found some website site tutorials but I always end up on having an error with the dependencies I have use on my react native project.
Maybe anyone can provide a good tutorial website regarding this? or have anyone tried the same approach? Any advice will help, thank you.

Did you see this article?

@tomerpacific The article is outdated. In RN >= 0.71, the Android folder with dependencies is missing.
@/MaroonDre - I'm facing the same issue. I think RN artifacts aren't included in the .AAR and need to be imported separately into the native project along with the .AAR.
